# Email Template HTML Images not appearing in gmail

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, email-templates

just created one email template for gmail

here is my html code.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>dance</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <table style="background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing: 0;margin:0 auto;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
     <tr>
         <td>
             <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                 <tr>
                     <td><a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                </td>
                </tr>
   <tr>
                     <td><a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                </td>
                </tr>
         <tr>
                     <td><a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>
```

it is displaying only 1 image while other images are not displaying..

**need help what am i doing wrong ?**

Comment: is there something wrong in syntax? I can see some closing tags, but there are no opening tags..

Comment: You need to host your images online. Relative links to images on your own computer won't work when the recipient opens the email.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the code carefully you posted here; The last image should be inside the table but it has a closing tag only `</table>`.  `<table>` open tag is missing in Layout.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Have you tried giving complete URL (ie, `http://<your_site_url>/images/top_logo_03.png`) to image instead of  `images/top_logo_03.png`??</strike>

Please check this code.

```
 <table style="background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing: 0;margin:0 auto;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
     <td>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tr>
                 <td><a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tr>
                 <td><a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tr>
                 <td><a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the images on a server

```
<a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="http://www.yourserver.com/images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/>
```

Luiggi

Answer (score 1):

If you check your code, the table structure is incorrect. For the first row of image, you have added end tag of table. For 2nd and 3rd row of image, extra tag of `</table>` is there, which gives the error of not displaying those images. The HTML code will be as below.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>dance</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <table style="background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing: 0;margin:0 auto;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong: try it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>dance</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table style="background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing: 0;margin:0 auto;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                     <td><a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a></td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a></td>
         </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="http://www.xxx.net.au/" title="title"><img src="images/top_logo_03.png" alt="title" width="657" height="252" border="0" style="display:block"/></a></td>
      </tr>
      </table>

   </body>
</html>
```

you had misplaced some tags

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your code first of all you can see your table structure is incorrect. Try correcting it.
Secondly you have used relative paths for your images. Try using absolute path for your images.
For Ex-
instead of `<img src="images/xyz.gif: />`, use `<img src="http:""www.example.com/images/xyz.gif">`